# Dynamic Graph Filtering

Tags: c#, wpf, graphing

I am working on a graph in WPF, in each section there are thousands of points to draw. The performance for rendering this graph is horrible.

Does anyone have any experience with a filter that will represent the graph with much fewer points - similar to the way a stock graph draws itself when its zoomed out.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you talk about a graph, I'm assuming you mean as in a chart rather than lots of nodes and edges (hence the stock example).

So, assuming that's the case, here are a couple of webpages covering algorithms for simplifying polylines:

http://www.kevlindev.com/tutorials/geometry/simplify_polyline/page2.htm

http://softsurfer.com/Archive/algorithm_0205/algorithm_0205.htm

You could generate simplified polyline versions of the graph lines for various scales (on demand).